# Caught DatabaseError while rendering

Tags: django, templates

The error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /some/location
Caught DatabaseError while rendering: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

The model:

```
class Price(models.Model):
    supermarket = models.ForeignKey(SuperMarket)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

The query:

```
def costs_of_product(product, supermarkets):
    filter1 = Price.objects.filter(product=product)
    return filter1.filter(supermarket__in=supermarkets)
```

while the result of `productList` is the result of a call of `costs_of_product`.

The template:

```
<ul>   
{% for pr in productList %}
    <li>{{ pr.supermarket }}: {{ pr.price }} € </li>
{% empty %}    
    <li>No products are available.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The **question**:
Why the aforementioned error is displayed at the first line of `for` in the template?

EDIT: Following the comment of `amateur`, I added this line in the view (none of the above snippets).

```
supermarkets = [supermarket.id for supermarket in supermarkets]
```

and then I called `costs_of_product()` and it worked! What is very curious is that when I move this line in the body of the function `costs_of_product()`, it does not work!

Comment: What is supermarkets in your .filter statement? u should use supermarket__id__in if your supermarkets are a list of ids and not the objects..

Comment: Indeed, the are not objects. Nonetheless, even the use of `supermarket__id__in` does not change anything in the observed behaviour.

Comment: You can use .values_list() to get the ids

Comment: `Cannot use a multi-field GeoValuesListQuerySet as a filter value.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Q. Something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def costs_of_product(product, supermarkets):
    filter1 = Price.objects.filter(Q(product=product) & Q(supermarket__in=supermarkets))
    return filter1
```

You use filter on list, so this can possiibly cause an error.

As for place - it's because Django try to render objects you got (and yes, Django got something from your function), but can't do it.

Comment: Same error. `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py in execute, line 44`